# JPA CriteriaQuery, querying multiple fields not returning results as expected

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, dao

I have a basic message board type system I'm developing in a spring based webapp.  I'm using spring 4.1.3 and hibernate 4.3.7.  I'm attempting to build a "universal" search bar to find posts that contain a specified value in one of many fields.  For starters, here is my post domain object:

```
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
        name = "POST_KEYWORD",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "POST_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "KEYWORD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
)
private Set<Keyword> keywords = new HashSet<>();
```

The author, category, and keyword objects are all very boring and all basically look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Keyword implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "keyword_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "keyword_id_seq", sequenceName = "keyword_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "KEYWORD_VALUE")
private String value;
private int count = 1;
```

}

The author and category classes don't have the int count, just simply id and value fields.

Here is my PostDao:

```
public List<Post> universalFind(String value, int maxResults) {
        // create a new string that is built for case insensitive "like" sql searches
    String upperValue = "%" + value.toUpperCase() + "%";

    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

     // build the criteria query and get the path for the category value
    CriteriaQuery<Post> postQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Post.class).distinct(true);
    Root<Post> postRoot = postQuery.from(Post.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    // find titles containing the value
    Predicate titlePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(postRoot.get(Post_.title)), upperValue);
    predicates.add(titlePredicate);        


    // find keywords containing the value
    SetJoin<Post, Keyword> postKeywords = postRoot.join(Post_.keywords);
    Path<String> keywordPath = postKeywords.get(Keyword_.value);
    Predicate keywordPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(keywordPath), upperValue);
    predicates.add(keywordPredicate);

    select.where(criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));

    TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select);
    List<Post> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

It all works as expected when all the data is populated in a Post object.  If I have two posts with "Test" in the title, and I search for "test", I will get both posts back.  However, if I remove all of the keywords from one of the posts, that post no longer shows up in the search results.  I can use pgadmin to verify it is in the database.

If I comment out the SetJoin section for the keyword in my DAO, the posts without keywords will suddenly appear in my searches.

Is there some way to prevent this, so that I can have a post without keywords and it will still show up in the results if the search term matches any one of the other fields?

EDIT: I cut this down to the bare minimum Frankenstein code I possibly could

Comment: You are including way too much code for anybody to wade through and attempt to solve your problem. Try whittling it down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can actually be examined. This is not a code review site.

Comment: really?  2 entity classes with no logic that only show properties/annotations, and the dao method that shows the CriteriaQuery with the predicates I'm building, that's way too much?  That seems like the minimum amount of code I could possibly include.

Comment: It's over 100 lines of code and nobody on this site is obligated to help you. It may be the minimum amount of code, but you went over three hours before *anybody* even so much as *commented* on your post. That's way way above average around here. I'm just providing some friendly advice. If you can't narrow the problem down for us then good luck solving it on your own.

Comment: I know nobody is obligated to help. I've been on this site for a long time. If you don't provide enough info, people let you know they can't help you without seeing the offending code. Literally, the first two code blocks are member variables, with JPA annotations, which are crucial to understanding the issue.  There's no sifting to be done, it's a simple bean.  The bottom code block is one CriteriaQuery that operates on the entity that I've shown, showing the predicates that define the query.  I'll go ahead and cut stuff out, but I strongly disagree that this is some crazy amount of code.